# What is the better way to store mdf file with installation

Tags: c#, database, winforms, relative-path, appdata

I made a perfect application and I have to make insallation for that app. But i have a localDB and there is my problem, how, and where to store mdf file.
I had searched about it on google but I haven't arrived at a solution yet.

I have tried two solutions.

1. Include mdf file to installation folder via exe file.
   When I do that , program starts and executes fine, database works untill i have update or insert commands, exception is thrown which says that db is read-only. I tried running with administrator or changing privilegies, but still same problem.
2. Save mdf file to mydocuments or appdata
   That way I create special folder via VS installer and add mdf file there, but problem is I don't know how to make relative connection string, because it is set to datadirectory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="Test1" connectionString=" Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Artikli.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Where other programs store their databases? What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to ask in a round-about way how to set the `DataDirectory` variable to a specific path?  If so, that has been covered many times; just type DataDirectory into the search box.  If you are really asking for a "best way" that is an opinion type question and will likely be closed as such.

Answer (score 1):

You should set up your connectionstring programmatically in some special folder in which the user will have access, like this:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\your folder\your app\your database.mdf";
        string connectionString = string.Format("Data Source = {0}; Integrated Security = True; providerName = System.Data.SqlClient;", path);
```

..and when the program starts you should verify if this database is already saved in the specified folder, if not, you can copy the database from installation folder to there.

```
File.Copy(Application.StartupPath + @"\your database.mdf", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\your folder\your app\your database.mdf");
```